# CCScrollView scroll and touch events never firing

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I can't find *any* helpful tutorials or explanation on how to use a `CCScrollView`. I have a grid-layout of sprites and labels (listing achievements for an iOS game). There are more than can fit on the screen so I want the user to be able to scroll.

To scroll, the user would swipe/pan upwards, to reveal the sprites etc which are lower.

I've found a few code samples and they seem to indicate you just need to add your content node to the scroll node and it will take care of the rest.

It doesn't seem to work. There's no scroll, and the pan/touch events on the scroll layer never seem to fire. The close button I have at the same child (sibling to the scroll view) no longer works as well.

I'm not using SpriteBuilder.

```
// Node to hold all sprites/labels
scrollContents = [CCNode node];

// I add a bunch of sprites/labels in a grid view
for( NSString *key in badgeKeys ){

    // logic to load the sprite would be here

    CCSprite *badge = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:frame];
    badge.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    badge.position = ccp(xPos,yPos);
    [scrollContents addChild:badge];

    // some logic to increment x/y position logic, for grid layout

}

// Scroll view
scrollView = [[CCScrollView alloc] initWithContentNode:scrollContents];
scrollView.horizontalScrollEnabled = NO;
scrollView.verticalScrollEnabled = YES;
[scrollView setBounces:NO];

// My sprites never even show unless I manually set this
scrollContents.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentSize.width,960);
NSLog(@"scrollContents contentsize: %f %f", scrollContents.contentSize.width,scrollContents.contentSize.height);

[self addChild:scrollView];
```

Comment: You need to set the scrollView.delegate to a class instance that implements the CCScrollViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : you 'could' or 'may' is more appropriate. The delegate is not mandatory, scroll view scrolls fine without the delegate.

Comment: @helion3 : you 'must' set the scroll view content size (different from the content node content size). Touch processing will not happen unless there is a content size defining the area in which the gesture recognizer will operate.

Comment: I assumed the question was related to the "touch events" of the scroll view delegate protocol not firing.

Comment: Every time I try setting the scroll view content size, for example to `600,600`, my contents vanish and no scroll actions works.

Comment: what version are you using ? scrollingMenu is a work in progress , i am with the most current 3.2.1 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, here is a working example (i deconstructed part of my code to give you a fully working code sample) of a scrolling menu with 'live' buttons inside. I just tested this 'deconstruction' , it works

```
- (void) scrollingMenuWithCharmsTest {

//    setup something to scroll

GameInventory *gi = [GameInventory sharedGameInventory];
while (gi.armorCharms.count < 20) {
    [gi addArmorCharm:[ArmorCharm createRandomArmorCharm]];
}

CCNode *contentNode = [self charmsContentNodeFor:gi.armorCharms
                                     showEquiped:NO
                         spacingBetweenMenuItems:8
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(onArmorCharmSelected:)];

// setup a clipping node to crop out the CCScrollingMenu


CCNodeColor *ccn = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor blackColor] width:180 height:200];
ccn.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);
CCClippingNode *cn = [CCClippingNode clippingNodeWithStencil:ccn];
cn.alphaThreshold = 0.05f;
[self addChild:cn];
cn.inverted            = NO;
cn.positionInPointsV   = ccp(50, 50);
cn.anchorPoint         = ccp(0, 0);
cn.contentSizeInPoints = CGSizeMake(180, 200);

// setup scrolling menu

CCScrollView * bsm = [[CCScrollView alloc] initWithContentNode:contentNode];
bsm.contentSize=CGSizeMake(180,200);

[cn addChild:bsm];
bsm.position                = ccp(0, 0);
bsm.bounces                 = YES;
bsm.pagingEnabled           = NO;
bsm.verticalScrollEnabled   = YES;
bsm.horizontalScrollEnabled = NO;

bsm.contentSizeInPoints = CGSizeMake(180, 200); // inPoints only after the node has a parent

for (CharmAbstractBoxMenuItem *lmi in bsm.contentNode.children) {
    TRACE(@"item %@ is at %@", lmi.item.description, NSStringFromCGPoint(lmi.positionInPointsV));
}
TRACE(@"number of pages : %i", bsm.numVerticalPages);

}

- (CCNode *)charmsContentNodeFor:(NSDictionary *)keyedItems
                     showEquiped:(BOOL)isShowEquiped
         spacingBetweenMenuItems:(float)inSpacing
                          target:(id)inTarget
                        selector:(SEL)inSelector {

NSSortDescriptor *sortOrder  = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray          *sortedKeys = [[keyedItems allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]];

float initialY = 0;
float currentY = initialY;

NSUInteger      itemNumber   = 0;
CGFloat         width        = 0;
CGFloat         height       = 0;
CCNode          *contentNode = [CCNode node];
for (NSUInteger loopi        = 0; loopi < [sortedKeys count]; loopi++) {
    NSString      *key = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:loopi];
    CharmAbstract *ci  = [keyedItems objectForKey:key];

    if (ci) {
        CharmAbstractBoxMenuItem *cmi = [CharmAbstractBoxMenuItem itemBoxFor:ci
                                                                      target:inTarget
                                                                    selector:inSelector
        ];

        cmi.toolTip  = ci.toolTip;
        cmi.position = ccp(deviceOffset(0), currentY);
        cmi.key      = key;
        [contentNode addChild:cmi z:0 name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long) itemNumber]];

        currentY += cmi.contentSizeInPoints.height + inSpacing;
        itemNumber++;
        if (cmi.contentSize.width > width) width = cmi.contentSize.width;
        height += cmi.contentSize.height;
        if (loopi < sortedKeys.count - 1) height += inSpacing;
    }
    else {
        MPLOG(@"*** Key [%@] yielded no items.", key);
    }

}
contentNode.contentSizeType = CCSizeTypePoints;
contentNode.contentSize     = CGSizeMake(width, height);
return contentNode;

}
```

some notes :

- i gave you my 'build content node' routine so you know the ins and outs of positions and sizes.
- my charmBoxMenuItemss derive from 'CCButton' and are hot ... In the full version of this code snippet, i extended CCScrollView to prevent the buttons from being 'hot' outside the crop area (although they are cropped out from view, they are still 'visible' by default, and could respond when a random tap occurs above or below the crop area).
- For clipping node with stencil, you need to add this in your setupCocos2dWithOptions line:

  CCSetupDepthFormat : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES]

[image: as seen on a simulator near you :)]

Comment: Comparing this to my code, I wound up realizing a few issues: I had my content positioned using normalized percents, so as I tweaked the content size, they shifted, sometimes off screen. Second, the scroll would never work because I had a custom pan gesture recognizer - so I added a check for a `CCScrollView` node to my `-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch`.