# How can I use CCClippingNode to cut the top and bottom of a CCTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm fairly new to Cocos2d and I'm "really" struggling with sizing a CCTableView. What I'm referring to is how can its height be controlled so that I have space at the top and the bottom.

I have my table view functioning and I'm trying to visually wrap the top and bottom with a sprite to provide the look and feel of a frame. But when I touch the table view to scroll
It up or down, it occupies most of the screen vertically. I started messing with the contentSize, thinking this would alter where each cell appears and disappears from the top and bottom. But this had no effect.

Having had s Google about, I'm reading that I have to use a Clipping Node with a Stencil? Coming from UIkit, this seems like a bit of a faff. Would anyone like to hazard at a tutorial, bit of code with a simple CCTableView representation, sat in the middle of the scene where each cell appears and dissapears under a content frame?

Comment: You should change the scroll view's contentSize to affect the area where it responds to touches.

Comment: I've tried that. But touching and holding the table view and dragging down makes it go to the bottom of the screen. I noticed you'd responded to another question of mine, coincidentally referring to scroll views. I'm not sure if it was you, but someone had suggested that using normalised contentSize floats sometimes caused strange results. Would you recommend using actual points to control contentSize then? Given I was crawling the wall with this, I've actually used several sprites, layered. One with transparency, a hole in the middle, for the cells. This way the scroll under the frame.

Comment: Not sure, theoretically contentSize could be in the range of 0.0 to 1.0 if the contentSizeType is set to %. This means if contentSizeType isn't set to the standard "points" type you should make assignments through contentSizeInPoints so that you don't accidentally assign a point size that will subsequently interpreted as percentages.

Comment: @CarlHine The code sample i pointed you to also has a clipping node clipping a scrolling menu. I guess it would not be too far for encapsulating a CCTableView. advice : if you use normalized, do all your sizing and layouts in onEnter : normalized relies heavily on the parent's properties. Here is the link to code sample : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521173/ccscrollview-scroll-and-touch-events-never-firing/26532544#26532544

Comment: Ah I'm with you. I do try to use normalised coords and sizes as frequent as possible for obvious reasons. In the first place, is my approach to managing a CCtableView the correct one? @LearnCocos2D. I have your book, (Good Book) had it while actually and I could not find CCTableView in the index. I just flicked through it last night for a possible best-practice for clipping. But found nothing. In point of fact, I have actually solved this problem by not using a clipping node at all. I've used the Z order of each child added to scene and left a transparent hole in my frame sprite.

Comment: @CarlHine : yes, i used another approach for the same, which was to extend the CCScrollView, specifically the update method. In there, i test to see if each 'cell' intersects with the view's boundingBox, and if not, i set its visible property to NO. This also cans touch processing on the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at CCCropNode in the cocos2d extensions package:

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-swift-ext/tree/master/Extensions/CCCropNode

the CCCropNode uses a glScissor to clip the drawing to a specified area: Much simpler than the CCClippingNode (which uses the stencil buffer).

Also this forum post might help:

http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/ccclippingnode-woes/14752

You'll still have issues with touches outside of the target region hitting into your scroll / table area (and I've found that the CCCropNode touch clipping doesn't work - need to investigate that as it is causing me problems).

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I Guess there's no real right answer here, just a lot of possible solutions. So I've upped your response too.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I managed to solve the touches outside the table region by adding code to CCScrollView.m as following:-

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(CCTouch *)touch
{
    // Added by Season
    //*************************************************************
    CGPoint lcgpTouch = [touch locationInWorld];
    if (!(lcgpTouch.x >= [self position].x && lcgpTouch.x <= [self position].x + [self contentSize].width &&
        lcgpTouch.y >= [self position].y && lcgpTouch.y <= [self position].y + [self contentSize].height)) {
        return NO;
    }
    //*************************************************************

    if (!_contentNode) return NO;
    if (!self.visible) return NO;
    if (!self.userInteractionEnabled) return NO;
```

And you are required to setContentSize to CCTableView in order to have this piece of code get the size correctly.

Additional info:
I have some CCSprite on top of the outside target region that suppose to response to touchBegan failed after the above coding, then I changed all CCSprite to CCButton and it works like a charm. You do not need to do what I did here, you can modify coding to allow CCSprite to response to touchBegan easily.

Hope this coding above help you all.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Many possible solutions to this, I suppose. I've a thread going on the cocos2d forum specific to this. I've upped your response as it is an answer but not sure if totally ideal. I ended up masking the surrounding area with a CCSprite with a transparent section in the middle. Worked a treat.